# Lazyloading not working with created entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I'm using DbContext, EF 6.1.3, and have lazy loading enabled. Lazy loading works fine with entries retrieved via queries, but not with newly created entities. Anyone know the reason why the behaviour is different? Here's an example below, which I've just run using Linqpad:

```
var job=BookingSet.Create();
BookingSet.Add(job);
job.GetType().Dump();
job.ContentClassID=1;
(job.ContentClass?.IsEmpty==null).Dump();

job = BookingSet.First(x=> x.ContentClassID == 1);
job.GetType().Dump();
(job.ContentClass?.IsEmpty==null).Dump();
```

If you're not familiar with it, Dump in this example is basically doing a print. I've not included the model details, but I don't think there that pertinent - behaviour is the same for a variety of entities I've tried it with

Here's the output:

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Booking_87C5BB16B1BBF0B2C1EEF997F61811A51402A5E75697491AA3D7A7922950FBE6

True

System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Booking_87C5BB16B1BBF0B2C1EEF997F61811A51402A5E75697491AA3D7A7922950FBE6

False
```

We've got an entity with a relationship to another entity. The first code block creates an entity and dumps its type, then tries to navigate to the related entity, but fails. The second code block loads an entity with the same foreign key value from the first example. It dumps its type and performs the same check as the first example, but this time, as you'd expect, the check works. In both instances we have a proxy class, but the first example doesn't lazy load

Comment: What is the primary key for the entity?

Comment: Weird, though I replied to this, but nothing is showing. PK for the job entity is an integer ID column, set as an identity. PK for the other entity is a manually set integer ID. Same behaviour if both entities use identities though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the official answer to this question from github:

EF6 and all earlier versions of EF do not do lazy loading for entities in the Added state. The main reason for this is that Added entities are tracked differently than other entities and don't have real keys. They also don't fixup in the same way. This means that the general case of lazy loading becomes inconsistent. In your case, where an Added entity is on the dependent end of a relationship and it's FK has been set, then it would be possible to do lazy loading correctly. However, even then, we haven't seen much demand for this, and given that it would make it inconsistent in ways that only make sense if you really understand what is going on under the covers, we decided to just not do lazy loading for Added entities.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for [`DSet.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679504(v=vs.113).aspx):

> Creates a new instance of an entity for the type of this set. Note that this instance is NOT added or attached to the set. The instance returned will be a proxy if the underlying context is configured to create proxies and the entity type meets the requirements for creating a proxy.

So rather than adding to your set, you need to attach it. Additionally, you need to set the value for the primary key property(s). So your code should be something like this:

```
var job=BookingSet.Create();
job.Id = 123;
BookingSet.Attach(job);

(job.ContentClass?.IsEmpty==null).Dump();
```

Comment: Hmm, gave it a try with attach, and setting the key values, but I'm still getting the same behaviour. Wouldn't help in general though, as this is a new value with an identity key, so I wouldn't know the key to use until the changes are committed. Also, if I use Attach, the entity would be added to the context in the state "Unchanged". Since it's a new entity it needs to be state "Added". To be honest, I was assuming it was supposed to behave this way, and was wondering why, but now I'm not so sure

Comment: I've just created a test database, two tables with a simple one to many FK relationship between them (ie, as in the original example) but with both tables having manually set PKs. Still get the same behaviour. Also, as I'd expect, trying to commit the changes with the created and attached entity does nothing - EF treats the attached object as unchanged